# javascript JSON access

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that goes somewhat like this:

```
var waitingGames = {
    arithemetic:[
        {
            games:[]
        },

        {
            games:[]
        },

        {
            games:[]
        }
    ]
```

and so on for synonyms, antonyms and translation. My problem is that I can't seem to access the games array by using this:

```
var gametype = url_parts.query.type;
var gamesize = url_parts.query.size;
if(games.waitingGames.gametype[gamesize].games.length == 0)
```

I get that gametype is undefined, even though I already tried printing the variable and it has the right value (arithemetic in the above example). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using variable keys to access values in JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922544/using-variable-keys-to-access-values-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: If your key name is stored in a variable, you have to reference it using the bracket notation `object[variableName]`. It makes sense that dot-notation wouldn't work since `object.variableName` implies that there is a property of the object named `variableName`, when it should be `keyName`, which is just stored in the variable.

Comment: Don't know if this is relative, but I'm getting this JSON object by using require: 
    var games = require('./gameJSONobj');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`games.waitingGames[gametype][gamesize].games.length`

Here you are using `gametype` as a variable like you meant to.

**See this proof-of-concept [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gRQx2/2/).**

Comment: like that i get a "unexpected token [" error,also tried without the dot and i get " cannot read property of 'arithemetic' of undefined =/

Comment: Sorry, typo on the `.`, edited.  Shouldn't `gametype` be equal to `"arithmetic"`?

Comment: Also, where are you defining `games`?  Does it work if you just write: `games[gametype][gamesize].games.length`

Comment: Yes, games is defined although from an explanation from above it might it it since i have var games = require(./gameJSONobj); and being waitingGames a variable inside that file, it won't work with the dot reference

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
if(games.waitingGames.arithemetic[gamesize].games.length == 0)
```

Comment: that would kinda ruin the point because im trying to pass to the function where it should be getting then games information from. Either way, like that I also get the  cannot read property of 'arithemetic' of undefined".

Comment: @user3152485 `waitingGames` is a variable name, not an object property, so you can't reference it by saying `games.waitingGames` -- that's why it's undefined.

Comment: That might be it.. any suggestion to go around it? because games has 3 variables inside it all too big to keep the main file clean.

Comment: Can you paste your complete json object  so that we can help you in better way ??

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value from inner games object using this expresson
`console.log(waitingGames.arithemetic[0].games);`

Use a for loop to loop through arithemetic array.

```
for(var i =0, j = waitingGames.arithemetic.length; i<j; i++){
    if(waitingGames.arithemetic.games.length == 0){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, had to use the brackets to change use the variable content to reach where i wanted inside the JSON object, thanks all