# Vue.js reuse filter

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js

I've made these 2 filters:

**Filter 1**

```
  Vue.filter('role',function(value,role)
        {
            if(!role || 0 === role.length)
            {
                return value;
            }
            return value.filter(function(item) {
                return item.role.RoleName == role
            });
        });
```

**Filter 2**

```
    Vue.filter('company',function(value,company)
        {
            if(!company || 0 === company.length)
            {
                return value;
            }
            return value.filter(function(item) {
                return item.department.company.CompanyName == role
            });
        });
```

Now I would like to combine them. Like this:

**Combine filters**

```
  Vue.filter('employeefilter',function(value,employeeinfo,filteron)
        {
            if(!employeeinfo || 0 === employeeinfo.length)
            {
                return value;
            }
            return value.filter(function(item) {
                return item.filteron == employeeinfo
            });
        });
```

And I pass this to the combined filter:

```
v-for="employee in list | employeefilter selectedrole 'role.RoleName'
```

But that is not working how could I fix that ^

EDIT

I pass it now like this:

```
v-for="employee in list | employeefilter selectedrole 'item.role.RoleName'| employeefilter selectedcompany item.department.company.CompanyId"
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [Using variable keys to access values in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922544/using-variable-keys-to-access-values-in-javascript-objects)

From that answer:

You can access object properties by dot notation or by bracket notation.

```
var x = {'test': 'hi'};
alert(x.test); // alerts hi
alert(x['test']); // alerts hi
```

When you have a dynamic value, you have to use the latter:

```
var property = 'test';
alert(x.property); // looks for x.property, undefined if it doesn't exist
alert(x[property]); // looks for x['test'], alerts hi
```

So you'll need to do:

```
return value.filter(function(item) {
    return item[filteron] == employeeinfo
});
```

Edit, actually that won't work as you also need to parse the `filteron` string (`item['role.RoleName']` wont work, `item['role']['RoleName']` is what you want.  Check out this answer for a function that will allow you to access a deep property of an object using a string: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Final code:

```
Object.byString = function(o, s) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in o) {
            o = o[k];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return o;
}

Vue.filter('employeefilter',function(value,employeeinfo,filteron)
    {
        if(!employeeinfo || 0 === employeeinfo.length)
        {
            return value;
        }
        return value.filter(function(item) {
            return Object.byString(value, filteron) == employeeinfo;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks this is brilliant(maybe a bit to far for me). But I understand it, I receive an error could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @jamie that means that `filteron` is undefined. I think you just need quotes around `'item.department.company.CompanyId'`:  `v-for="employee in list | employeefilter selectedrole 'item.role.RoleName'| employeefilter selectedcompany 'item.department.company.CompanyId'"`