# How to use the key of an object

Tags: javascript

If there is:

```
var obj = {a: 'This is a', b: 'This is b', c: 'This is c'}
var select = 'b';
```

How can I make to work something like this:

```
console.log(obj.select); // This would output: This is b
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Using variable keys to access values in JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922544/using-variable-keys-to-access-values-in-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```js
var obj = {
  a: 'This is a',
  b: 'This is b',
  c: 'This is c'
}
var select = 'b';
console.log(obj[select]);
```