# Access object key using variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript, How to access object key(property) using variable?

for example:

```
interface Obj {
    a: Function;
    b: string;
}

let obj: Obj = {
    a: function() { return 'aaa'; },
    b: 'bbbb'
}

for(let key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

but typescript throw below error message:

> 'TS7017 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'obj' has no index signature'

How to fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To compile this code with `--noImplicitAny`, you need to have some kind of type-checked version of `Object.keys(obj)` function, type-checked in a sense that it's known to return only the names of properties  defined in `obj`.

There is no such function built-in in TypeScript AFAIK, but you can provide your own:

```
interface Obj {
    a: Function;
    b: string;
}

let obj: Obj = {
    a: function() { return 'aaa'; },
    b: 'bbbb'
};


function typedKeys<T>(o: T): (keyof T)[] {
    // type cast should be safe because that's what really Object.keys() does
    return Object.keys(o) as (keyof T)[];
}


// type-checked dynamic property access
typedKeys(obj).forEach(k => console.log(obj[k]));

// verify that it's indeed typechecked
typedKeys(obj).forEach(k => {
    let a: string = obj[k]; //  error TS2322: Type 'string | Function' 
                           // is not assignable to type 'string'.
                          //  Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.
});
```

Comment: This is awesome complicated. It would be an argument against TS. I would if there is not a simpler solution.

Comment: Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388993/how-to-use-dynamic-variable-as-import-a-module-namespace-in-node-js-typescript?noredirect=1#comment133024100_75388993

Answer (score 32):

You can also do something like this:

```
const keyTyped = key as keyof typeof Obj;
const value = Obj[keyTyped];
```

Comment: It worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 9):

I found using `keyof` to be the easiest solution

```
const logKey = (key: keyof Obj) => {
    console.log(obj[key])
}

for(let key in obj) {
    logKey(key)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved via below code:

```
// interface
export interface IDepartment {
  name: string
  code: string
}

let fieldName = 'name' as keyof IDepartment

// access value of provided field-name from object
deptObj[fieldName]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra function for iteration. TS infers type inside function in a more meaningful way:

```js
interface Obj {
    a: Function;
    b: string;
}

let obj: Obj = {
    a: function () { return 'aaa'; },
    b: 'bbbb'
}

const iterator = <T extends Obj>(obj: T) => {
    for (let key in obj) {
        console.log(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZQ5OALmQDEBXEBMYAexAG4Cj0yBnMKUAcxYC%20ePABsIYZPSxkM2ALy5WhUshjVaDEMgAUASlzIo4ylC0ByOJbNNkAgDRLk7ZGfRv0ZvELwJGXZMCQUHBg9FDICgA8ACrIEAAekCAAJhxoWAB82lKYZNH6chmKRKphOmISANYQAJ4BWjn6%20CUlviAc9GIAdCL0vNlYANrVNQC6uiwlQkJAA)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach((value, key) => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Or

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    return `${key} - ${value}`
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried your code above as a quick test in WebStorm, and it compiled and ran without error. If you are using a version of Typescript before 2.0, I suggest trying Typescript 2.0 or higher.