# In TypeScript, how to set the index signature of an object that is the property of a class?

Tags: typescript

Here is a class:

```
export class Survey {
    isCompleted: boolean;
    response: {
        'devices': string[];
        'languages': string[];
        'frameworks': string[];
        'backend': string[];
    };
}
```

I'm getting the "*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '...' has no index signature*" error when trying the following:

```
return Object.keys(user1.response).map(key => {
        return percentageMatch(user1.response[key], user2.response[key]) * categoryScores[key];
    })
```

`user1` and `user2` are instances of the `Survey` class.

I know how to set an index signature with simple object literals but how do I do it with the properties of the `response` object, which is itself a property of the `Survey` class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That required adding an index type `[key: string]: string[]` to the `response` type:

```
export class Survey {
    isCompleted: boolean;
    response: {
        [key: string]: string[],
        devices: string[],
        languages: string[],
        frameworks: string[],
        backend: string[],
    };
}
```

You can check it out in the [TypeScript Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Survey%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isCompleted%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20devices%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20languages%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20frameworks%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backend%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20user%3A%20Survey%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.keys(user.response).map(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(user.response%5Bkey%5D)%20%2F%2F%20no%20error!%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A) that I created.

You could also consider reducing repetition here and extract known keys to a string literal type:

```
type ResponseKeys = 'devices' | 'languages' | 'frameworks' | 'backend';

export class Survey {
    isCompleted: boolean;
    response: {
        [key in ResponseKeys]: string[]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Index signature is required because `Object.keys()` loses type information and returns string arrays.

You can introduce [your own function which is similar to `Object.keys()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41994659/43848) but is declared to return an array of actual object keys:

```
function typedKeys<T>(o: T): (keyof T)[] {
    // type cast should be safe because that's what really Object.keys() does
    return Object.keys(o) as (keyof T)[];
}
```

Then, there will be no error in a function that iterates keys of one object and accesses another object, if the objects are of the same type:

```
export class Survey {
    isCompleted: boolean;
    response: {
        'devices': string[];
        'languages': string[];
        'frameworks': string[];
        'backend': string[];
    };
}

function f(user1: Survey, user2: Survey) {
    return typedKeys(user1.response).map(key => {
        return user1.response[key] == user2.response[key];
    })
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, although it's not entirely correct – there's a nuance when you use `Object.keys(…)` on objects with non-enumerable properties.

Comment: I don't quite understand the nuance - are you talking about the case when `keyof` type operator returns keys for properties which are implemented as non-enumerable, so there is a discrepancy between the types and actual values?

Comment: Yes! That's probably why `Object.keys` doesn't have `(keyof T)[]` type definition in TypeScript by default.

Comment: Well, there no way to represent enumerable vs non-enumerable in the type system AFAIK. So whoever chooses to implement some property as non-enumerable should suffer the consequences :)

Comment: Well, I agree, although this should be kept in mind.