# What means [key in string] used to write an array's entries signatures?

Tags: typescript, fabricjs, typescript-typings

I was reading about [interfaces with index signatures](https://2ality.com/2020/02/typing-arrays-typescript.html#objects-that-are-also-array-ish%3A-interfaces-with-index-signatures) which allows to write an interface like this for an array:

```
interface StringArray {
  [index: number]: string;
}
```

And also i saw this example from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555001/1705922) which allows writting signature in this way too:

```
type ResponseKeys = 'devices' | 'languages' | 'frameworks' | 'backend';

export class Survey {
  isCompleted: boolean;
     response: {
       [key in ResponseKeys]: string[]
     };
 }
```

but what means [key in string] i found [somewhere in a doc](https://binarapps.com/integrate-fabric-js-canvas-drawing-library-with-react-app-via-uncontrolled-component/) :

```
const [texts, setTexts] = useState<{ [key in string]: fabric.ITextboxOptions }>({
  '0': { text: 'A', left: 0 },
  '1': { text: 'B', left: 30 },
  '2': { text: 'C', left: 60 },
});
```

even when i tried to read about the '[in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)' i couldn't find a meaning to test if a key is in a string type.
Any clue please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this

```
interface Invalid {
  [key in string]: string;
}

interface Valid {
  [key: string]: string;
}

type ValidType = {
  [key in string]: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgG5wDbACbIDeAUMsgNoDWEAnsqMgM5hSgDmAugFxMvsDcxAL7FioSLEQoAajnxFSFajR7NWITqr4bBI4mBoAHGXLwAVIygC8CslVr0QvdZucDhQA)

`type` is more flexible and will accept both syntaxes. Also `[key in type]` is more flexible and will allow some uses that `in` does not, but I don't have them at hand.

As of why do they exist? I don't know...

---

Original answer:

The `{ [key in string]: T }` is kind of a wildcard. It means the object assigned must have only string keys.

- `'property'` is ok
- `'0'` is ok
- `0` is not

```
const obj: { [key in string]: number } = {};

obj['0'] = 1; // ok
obj[0] = 1; // not ok!
obj.property = 1; // ok
```

Comment: {[index: string]: string;} doesn't require the object must have string keys too ?. I also still wonder the use of the in operator for the meaning you have said. Thanks for the confirmation anyway