# How can I access index within object using a variable name in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following object defined:

```
const routes = {
  "/": {},
  "/abc": {},
};
```

Now I want to access one of the objects within routes using the index with a variable name:

```
const indextoFind = "/abc";
const item = routes[indextoFind];
```

Typescript throws:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "/": {}; "/abc": {}; }'.   No
> index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{
> "/": {}; "/abc": {}; }'.

The index is clearly a string so I don't know why it won't allow me to access an object using a string variable.

Also, this works perfectly fine:

```
const item = routes["/abc"];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access object key using variable in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993515/access-object-key-using-variable-in-typescript)

Comment: Please provide reproducable example. If you try your code in TS playground it will work as expected

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this error occurs is most often when you try to specify some kind of string as a key and the TypeScript compiler cannot resolve this type because it can be any string. To solve this issue, you can use something like `keyof typeof` or just `keyof` to get the keys of your object.

Example:

```
const routes = {
  "/": {},
  "/abc": {},
};

const indexToFind: keyof typeof routes = 'someInput'; // will not work
const item = routes[indexToFind];
const otherIndex: keyof typeof routes = '/';
const item2 = routes[otherIndex];
```

A better and more useful example would be to have some kind of function that expects a key from an object:

```
const findSomething = (key: keyof typeof routes): Object => {
  return routes[key];
}
```

[Reproduction link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAUDGAIgHpCAuHAXwBp8jiBDAI2HKtsoG5ddRJYAlmAAmKAB4AVEADEhwigGsUATxAAzGFGUAHFOvhJU6LAHIIIALYoAkmG3ITnGMWIwA7gIA2nmGBCw3EDgFXnBoGAFUC0wDZDQAbTlxKVkRAF1uPnD-AAsUOFtRMUUVfS1dfQQ44xgTYkdQ-giogCYYqqN43PzC8QyeLNg1OQBlSxQoHKEAcxiACiVlEtUNcr0NDrQASgoAeSYAKxRgWAwAPhw6OAnEODBYzsX+yiA)