# jQuery get data from JSON file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make a simple multilanguage site! 
I have 3 buttons for 3 languages, when I press one of them, I get the value of that button value with jQuery and store it in a variable named `clicked` and I want to get data from JSON like this: `data.clicked.name`

How can i get the value of `clicked` on data.clicked.name?

html file

```
<div id="container">
    <input class="btnL" type="button" value="MK">
    <input class="btnL" type="button" value="EN">
    <input class="btnL" type="button" value="AL">
  </div>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".btnL").click(function () {
        var clicked = $(this).attr("value");

        $.getJSON('language.json', function (data) {
          console.log(data.clicked.name);
          // ex. if the value of clicked variable is="EN" 
          //     I want to get this console.log(data.EN.name) 
        });

      });
    });
  </script>
```

language.json

```
{
  "EN": {
    "name": "Name",
    "surname": "Surname"
  },
  "AL": {
    "name": "Emri",
    "surname": "Mbiemri"
  },
  "MK": {
    "name": "Име",
    "surname": "Презиме"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variable keys to access values in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922544/using-variable-keys-to-access-values-in-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 4):

Use brackets

```
console.log(data[clicked].name);
```

Comment: Oh damn! I was so close! I tried console.log(data.[clicked].name); but now it works with your solution! Thanks a lot!!