# Styling html elements with objects keys and values

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to style a `button` with a loop through the object's keys and values.
Values are working but keys are not.

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let obj = {color: 'red'}
Object.keys(obj).map(f=>btn.style.f = obj[f])
```

So, finally it would render like this `btn.style.color = 'red'`

but `btn.style.f`, f is not taking but if replace the `f` with `color` then it's working.

Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access btn.style's attribute like this as the [attribute is dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922544/using-variable-keys-to-access-values-in-javascript-objects),

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(f=>btn.style[f] = obj[f])
```

As mentioned in the above link,

> You can access object properties by dot notation or by bracket
> notation.
>
> ```
> var x = {'test': 'hi'};
> alert(x.test); // alerts hi
> alert(x['test']); // alerts hi
> ```
>
> When you have a dynamic value, you have to use the latter:
>
> ```
> var property = 'test';
> alert(x.property); // looks for x.property, undefined if it doesn't exist
> alert(x[property]); // looks for x['test'], alerts hi
> ```
>
> So what you actually want is:
>
> ```
> alert(data[bsID][0].time);
> ```

Besides as @charlietfl mentioned, you should use `Object.keys(obj).forEach()` instead of `.map()`.

Comment: This answer could benefit from some sort of an explanation.

Comment: Using `map()` is the wrong tool for the job

Comment: That should be a comment for the post itself. @charlietfl

Comment: A good answer should mention that issue, not continue with bad practice

Comment: Just did. Thanks :)

Comment: using `forEach`, so it will not return anything. is that correct?

Comment: Yes. map is for when you want to do some mutation for all of the item in the array and return a new array with the mutation. For just looping .forEach should be used.