# Javascript use value in for loop as object key?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, for-of-loop

I have a json that looks like this:

```
const sitesList = 
{"sites": {
  "miami": {
    "name": "Miami Beach"
  },
  "london": {
    "name": "London Bridge"
  }
}}
```

I also have a function that takes an array as parameter. The values in this array might be "london", "miami" or both etc. This is the function:

```
async function readPDF2(sites) {
  for (const value of sites) {
    console.log(sitesList.sites.value.name);
  }
}
```

The function is called like this: `readPDF2(['miami']);`

Now the problem is that when I do `sitesList.sites.value.name`, Javascript interprets `value` as an actual part of the json object. This makes sense, but how do I get around this? I want it to treat `value` as the constant declared in the for loop.

See this image:

[image]

How would I obtain this? **Thanks for any input!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variable keys to access values in JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922544/using-variable-keys-to-access-values-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: Enclose `value` in square braces to use it as an expression that evaluates to a key: `console.log(sitesList.sites[value].name);`

Comment: Thanks @danh, this was the solution I was looking for :)

Comment: ```Object.values(sitesList.sites).forEach((value)=>{console.log(value.name)})```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const sitesList = {
  "sites": {
    "miami": {
      "name": "Miami Beach"
    },
    "london": {
      "name": "London Bridge"
    }
  }
}


const sites = sitesList.sites;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sites)) {
  console.log(`Key: ${key} value: ${value.name}`)
}
```

Or you can use [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
const sitesList = {
  "sites": {
    "miami": {
      "name": "Miami Beach"
    },
    "london": {
      "name": "London Bridge"
    }
  }
}


const sites = sitesList.sites;
for (const site in sites) {
  console.log(`Key: ${site} value: ${sites[site].name}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sitesList = {
  "sites": {
    "miami": {
      "name": "Miami Beach"
    },
    "london": {
      "name": "London Bridge"
    }
  }
}
//If you need only Value then try this,
Object.values(sitesList.sites).forEach((value)=>{console.log(value.name)})

//If you need only Key then try this,

Object.keys(sitesList.sites).forEach(key=>{console.log(key)})

//If you need both Key and Value then try this,

Object.entries(sitesList.sites).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value.name}`))
```